# Apktool removes boolean from static field when recompiled

Tags: android, apk, decompiling, apktool

I am getting very strange results using Apktool in windows:

What I do:

1. I decompile the original APK file - `1.apk` in cmd using this command:
   `apktool d 1.apk`
2. Then, without making any changes to any of the files, I compile the `1` folder again using this command:
   `apktool b 1`
3. Then, I decompile the new apk file `2.apk` from the `dist` folder with this command:
   `apktool d 2.apk`
4. Lastly, I compare folders `1` and `2` and there is a a difference for some of the declared static fields:

Original decomplied file `1.apk`:

```
.field public static savedConf:Z = false
.field public static as:Ljava/lang/String; = ""
.field public static isReady:Z = false
```

The recompiled and then decompiled `2.apk` file:

```
.field public static savedConf:Z = false
.field public static as:Ljava/lang/String; = ""
.field public static isReady:Z
```

It is strange because the `= false` part in the `2.apk` file is missing only for some of the static fields in several various files.
Also, signing or not the `2.apk` file, has no effect on the outcome.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: No unfortunately I haven't. Problem still exists.